# Python Twitch IRC bot disconnecting after a period of time

Tags: python, bots, irc

So I have written a little bot that connects to twitch and is suppose to stay active till I close the script, but it seems after a elongated period of time the bot stops being connected to twitch and stops receiving anything. I think it is disconnecting, but I have no proof. Just the fact that it doesn't do anything after a while.

```
irc = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
irc.connect((server, port))
irc.send("PASS " + password + "\n")
irc.send("NICK " + name + "\n")
irc.send("JOIN " + channel + "\n")

def main():
while True:
    data = irc.recv(1204)
    data = data.strip('\r\n')
    sendUsr = data.split(" ")
    sendUsr = sendUsr[0]
    sendUsr = sendUsr.split("!")
    sendUsr = sendUsr[0]
    sendUsr = sendUsr.strip(":")


    print (data)

    if data.find('PING') != -1 :
        irc.send("PONG")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if data.find('PING') != -1 :
irc.send("PONG")
```

Needs to be changed to:

```
if data.find('PING')
irc.send("PONG :tmi.twitch.tv")
```

Try doing that & it should work.

Comment: when I do that it always returns true and runs every time it receives text

Comment: Try:

 data.find("PING") != -1 :

Comment: also with the double " and not single ' ??